# How to run unit tests with Cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, cypress

I have been using [Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/) to run [end-to-end tests](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/end-to-end-e2e-testing/). Recently, I have been using it to run [unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) as well. However, I have some issues with some small helper `functions` that I have built with [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/).

I have a create file called `utils.spec.js` in the following path `<my-project-name>/cypress/integration/unit/utils.spec.js` & I have written the following tests:

**File:** `utils.spec.js`

```
// Path to utils.js which holds the regular helper javascript functions
import { getTicketBySummary } from '../../path/to/utils';

describe('Unit Tests for utils.js methods', () => {
  /**
   * Array of objects mocking Tickets Object response
   */
  const mockedTickets = {
    data: {
      issues: [
        {
          id: 1,
          key: 'ticket-key-1',
          fields: {
            summary: 'This is ticket number 1',
          },
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          key: 'ticket-key-2',
          fields: {
            summary: 'This is ticket number 2',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  const mockedEmptyTicketsArray = [];
  it('returns an array containing a found ticket summary', () => {
    expect(
      getTicketBySummary({
        issues: mockedTickets,
        summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 1',
      })
    ).eq(mockedTickets.data.issues[0]);
  });
  it('returns an empty array, when no ticket summary was found', () => {
    expect(
      getTicketBySummary({
        issues: mockedTickets,
        summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 3',
      })
    ).eq(mockedEmptyTicketsArray);
  });
});
```

**File:** `utils.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Method to search for an issue by its title
 * Saving the search result into an array
 *
 * @param {array} - issues - an array containing all existing issues.
 * @param {string} - summaryTitle - used to search an issue by title
 */
const getTicketBySummary = ({ issues, summaryTitle }) =>
  issues.data.issues.filter(issueData => {
    return issueData.fields.summary === summaryTitle ? issueData : null;
  });

/**
 * Method to read a file's content
 * Returns another string representing the file's content
 *
 * @param {str} - file - a passed string representing the file's path
 */
const readFileContent = file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = { getTicketBySummary, readFileContent };
```

However, when I run the command: `npx cypress run --spec=\"cypress/integration/unit/utils.spec.js\" --env mode=terminal`, I get the error:`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`.

Also if I commented out the `fs` import & its `function` I get another error:

```
1) An uncaught error was detected outside of a test:
     TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure
```

I did some digging on the second error & it seems the `describe` method is `defined`. How can I fix both issues? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cypress gives you a command [cy.readfile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html#Examples) which is a lot easier than your `readFileContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tasks](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Usage) to execute node code. In your `plugins.js` create the task with the arguments you need, returning the calculated value:

```
  on('task', {
    // you can define and require this elsewhere
    getTicketBySummary('getTicketBySummary', { issues, summaryTitle }) {
      return issues.data.issues.filter(...);
    }
  })
}
```

In your test, execute the task via `cy.task`:

```
  it('returns an array containing a found ticket summary', () => {
    cy.task('getTicketBySummary', {
      issues: mockedTickets,
      summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 1',
    }).then(result => {
      expect(result).eq(mockedTickets.data.issues[0]);
    })
  });
```

That being said, `getTicketBySummary` looks like a pure function that doesn't depend on `fs`. Perhaps separate helper functions that actually need `node` as that could avoid need `cy.task`. If you want to be able to import commonjs (require) via ES6 import/export you would usually need to setup build tools (babel/rollup/etc) to be able to resolve that effectively.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Tks, I got it to work with you solution. However, I get this error now: `expected **{ Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }** to equal **undefined**` any ideas?

Comment: I have asked another question for this issue if you're interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106349/getting-error-while-unit-testing-my-own-node-modules-with-cypress-io