# Getting error while unit testing my own Node modules with Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, cypress

[Following this previous question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055150/how-to-run-unit-tests-with-cypress-io). I was able to start using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to unit test my Node's module by using the [task()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Syntax) method. However, I'm getting an error which I have been trying to debug or find a reference online but I haven't been able to.

```
cy:command ✘  assert    expected **{ Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }** to equal **[]**
```

What's this `{ Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }`? How can I get the actual `array` of `objects` instead?

**EDIT:** Included `assertions` & `task` code.

**File:**`utils.spec.js`

```
describe('Unit Tests for utils.js methods', () => {
  /**
   * Array of objects mocking Tickets Object response
   */
  const mockedTickets = {
    data: {
      issues: [
        {
          id: 1,
          key: 'ticket-key-1',
          fields: {
            summary: 'This is ticket number 1',
          },
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          key: 'ticket-key-2',
          fields: {
            summary: 'This is ticket number 2',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  const mockedEmptyTicketsArray = [];

  it('returns an array containing a found ticket summary', () => {
    expect(
      cy.task('getTicketBySummary', {
        issues: mockedTickets,
        summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 1',
      })
    ).eq(mockedTickets.data.issues[0]);
  });
  it('returns an empty array, when no ticket summary was found', () => {
    expect(
      cy.task('getTicketBySummary', {
        issues: mockedTickets,
        summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 3',
      })
    ).eq(mockedEmptyTicketsArray);
  });
});
```

**File:**`plugins/index.js

```
on('task', {
    getTicketBySummary({ issues, summaryTitle }) {
      issues.data.issues.filter(issueData => {
        return issueData.fields.summary === summaryTitle ? issueData : null;
      });
    },
  });
```

Comment: Please share the assertion and the task code.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I have added the assertions & task code.

Comment: Why are you using a task? `cy.task()` does not behave like a normal JS function, it returns a Chainable object which cannot be used inside an expect like that. In the previous question `getTicketBySummary` is a simple array filter. It should be in `/cypress/support/index.js` then you have no need to call a task, and less complexity.

Comment: @Ackroydd there is more code in that file that requires Node's module that's why

Comment: Actually, no - the use of `fs` can be replaced with `cy.readfile()`. But aside from that, the `expect(cy.task(...` syntax is wrong, you are getting an error. Why did you accept the answer?

Comment: The syntax should be `cy.task(...).then(taskResult => { expect(taskResult).to.eq(...`

Comment: @Ackroydd there is more to the implementation than to `readfile` method which it's irrelevant. I accepted the answer because aside from the syntax error, it led me in the right direction. It's the assertion that gets an error & not the imports

Comment: That is unfortunate, since it's going to mislead others. I submitted a correction (the same I gave you a minute ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by returning the `task`'s value like so:

**File:** `plugins/index,js`

```
on('task', {
    getTicketBySummary({ issues, summaryTitle }) {
      return issues.data.issues.filter(issueData => {
        return issueData.fields.summary === summaryTitle ? issueData : null;
      });
    },
  });
```

After I updated my code to use the `then()` method & assert the passed `param` value instead like so:

**File:** `utils.spec.js`

```
it('returns an empty array, when no ticket summary is found', () => {
    cy.task('getTicketBySummary', {
        issues: mockedTickets,
        summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 3',
     }).then(result => expect(result).to.deep.equal(emptyArray));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, you have been given the wrong syntax in the previous answer.

Cypress task is a command that returns a Chainable. You need to use `.then()` to get the value, so the calling order needs to be different.

```js
it('returns an array containing a found ticket summary', () => {

  cy.task('getTicketBySummary', { issues: mockedTickets, summaryTitle: 'This is ticket number 1' })
    .then(result => expect(result).to.eq(mockedTickets.data.issues[0]) );

});
```

Comment: When I used `then()` method it seems the `result` passed `param` is `null`. I think it's because I need to return the `value` from the `plugins/index.js` file? 
`on('task', {
    getTicketBySummary({ issues, summaryTitle }) {
      issues.data.issues.filter(issueData => {
        return issueData.fields.summary === summaryTitle ? issueData : null;
      });
    },
  });`

Comment: Ok, I got it: `on('task', {
    getTicketBySummary({ issues, summaryTitle }) {
      return issues.data.issues.filter(issueData => {
        return issueData.fields.summary === summaryTitle ? issueData : null;
      });
    },
  });` Can you update your answer with task syntax?

Comment: You should always return a value from the task, `return issues.data.issues.filter(issueData => issueData.fields.summary === summaryTitle)`.